# How can i use PDFKt with django python

Tags: python, django, pdf

I need to process the uploaded PDF blank form and then extract the fields and then save that in database.

i can use command line like

`pdfkt myform.pdf dump_data_fields` but i don't know how i can do in django

any deas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more of a Python thing. You can use Python `subprocess` package. It allows you to start subprocesses and interact with it using it's stdin, stdout, and stderr. Here is an example of how you can invoke your command in Python (or Django):

```
from subprocess import check_output

command = 'pdfkt %s dump_data_fields' % path
output = check_output(command, shell=True)
# do some processing here on output
```